# What's wrong with my code? ( java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, xml, http

I have this function:

```
public static String getXML(int id, int choose, int foo){    
        String line = null;
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = null;
            if(id == 100)
            {
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/logFollow.php?id="+ foo + "");
            }
            else if(id == 20)
            {
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/logMyTimeLine.php?id="+ foo + "");
            }
            else if(id == 19)
            {
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/logMyEntity.php?id="+ foo + "");
            }
            else if(choose == 1)
            {
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/log.php?id="+ id + "");
            }
            else if(choose == 2)
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/log2.php?id="+ id + "");
            else if(choose == 3)
                httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/comments.php?tag="+ id + "");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");

        }
```

All the String URL works fine except for the first ULR which is:

```
    if(id == 100)
    {
        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://andronekat.com/sawalef/logFollow.php?id="+ foo + "");
    }
```

it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException in this line

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I don't know from where I got the null. The link is working fine if I put it in the browser. Can anyone help me please?

Logcat:

```
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softshell.sowalef/com.softshell.sowalef.Follow}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at com.softshell.sowalef.Follow.onCreate(Follow.java:71)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-28 09:37:34.500: E/AndroidRuntime(21842):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output of the exception (log the exception in the catch block if necessary)

Comment: Which line of code is Follow.java:71? The only thing that can cause a NPE on the line you listed is if `httpClient` is `null`. From the code you posted, that seems impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Are you *certain* that `id` is set to 100 in the failing case?

Even if you *are,* you have a hole in your code that should be fixed. Specifically, the case where `id` is neither `100`, `20` nor `19` and `choose` is neither `1`, `2` nor `3`.

And, if that's not your *specific* problem here (I warrant that it should still be fixed), you should also check your values for `httpPost` and `httpClient` before the `execute` call so you can more easily figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes I'm sure of it. It goes inside the statement. The id & choose has to be one of the numbers nothing else. @paxdiablo

Comment: @mostashaar, see the bit about checking the variables for NULL. If that's still not the problem, I'd suspect you have an issue outside the scope of the information in your question.